# GraalVM how to return an array from a method to the guest language?

Tags: javascript, java, truffle, graalvm

I'm playing around with GraalVM (Truffle) in OpenJDK 17, and would like to know what the correct way is to return values to the guest language from method calls? Right now I'm struggling with passing a `String[]` array back.

**Exmaple:**

Java (host)

```java
class Services
{
    Value message;

    @HostAccess.Export
    public String[] getArrayString()
    {
        return new String[]{"s1", "s2", "s3"};
    }

    @HostAccess.Export
    public void setMessage( Value v )
    {
        message = v;
        message.pin();
    }
}

...

String jsScript = " ... " // see below
try ( Context context = Context.newBuilder().allowHostAccess(HostAccess.SCOPED).build() )
{
    Services s = new Services();
    context.getBindings("js").putMember("services", s);
    context.eval("js", jsScript);
}
```

JavaScript (guest)

```js
var a = services.getArrayString();
b = '';
for ( var c in a ) b += c;
services.setMessage('' + a + ' // ' + b)
```

The final message value is `"[object Object] // "` (b is blank), however I expected something like `"[object Object] // s1s2s3"`.

I've also tried the return types `Object[]` and `ArrayList<String>`. I'm not sure why I can't access the elements of the array, either I'm not passing the array back correctly, or I'm not accessing it correctly within the JavaScript script. The examples I've found in the GraalVM docs are always about passing values directly from the host to the guest, but I'd like to do it via a method call - how is that done?

Answer (score 0):

I've finally found a way to pass an *array* from the host to the guest - using `ProxyArray`.

https://www.graalvm.org/22.1/reference-manual/embed-languages/#computed-arrays-using-polyglot-proxies

Reading through the Graalvm documentation and experimenting with the very primative examples they provide, I came up with the following changes to my `Services` class:

```java
    ArrayList<String> array = new ArrayList<String>();

    @HostAccess.Export
    public void prepareList()
    {
        array.add("s1");
        array.add("s2");
        array.add("s3");
    }

    @HostAccess.Export
    public ProxyArray getArray()
    {
        return new ProxyArray() {

            @Override
            public Object get( long index )
            {
                return array.get((int)index);
            }

            @Override
            public void set( long index, Value value )
            {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            }

            @Override
            public long getSize()
            {
                return array.size();
            }
        };
    }
```

And finally the guest call looks like this:

```js
services.prepareList();
var a = services.getArray();
b = '';
for ( i = 0; i < a.length; i++ ) b += a[i];
services.setMessage('' + a + ' // ' + b)
```

And the value of the message is then as expected `"[object Object] // s1s2s3"`

Hope someone finds this useful ... and if you have a better way of returning objects (Array, Hashtable, whatever) post your answers here - thanks.

Answer (score 0):

First I would give a straight forward answer to your question. To pass an array from Java scope to the guest language scope, you can just send the Java array/list as input to the execute method. For example:

```
Context context = Context.newBuilder().allowAllAccess(true).build();
int intArray[] = {1,2,3};
Value ret = context.eval("js", "(function getArray(a) {console.log(a[2]);})").execute(intArray);
```

The above should print `3` in the JS scope.

Now I decide to add the following paragraphs because after reading your code as well as those in some proposed answers, I think it could be of help.

Say you have a Java code snippet like the one below which returns an array from the JS context.

```
Value val = context.eval("js", "(function getArray() {return [1,2,3];})").execute();
```

It is not possible to directly access the whole array object from `val` in the Java language scope because the memory layout of Java arrays is different from the memory layout of JS arrays. However you can obtain elements at different indices of the JS array from within the Java scope as follows:

```
 int index2 = val.getArrayElement(2).asInt();
 System.out.println(index2);
```

The above should print the value `3`.

In order to obtain the full array in the Java scope, you must do an explicit array copy. The classic way to do this is to leverage the technique described here: https://www.graalvm.org/sdk/javadoc/org/graalvm/polyglot/Value.html#as-org.graalvm.polyglot.TypeLiteral-

Using that technique one can define an `INTEGER_LIST` TypeLiteral as such:

```
   public static final TypeLiteral<List<Integer>> INTEGER_LIST =
            new TypeLiteral<List<Integer>>() {};
```

And then return the polyglot Value as an `INTEGER_LIST` as follows:

```
List<Integer> intList = context.eval("js", "(function getArray() {return [1,2,3];})").execute().as(INTEGER_LIST);        
System.out.println("JS array in Java scope: " + intList);
```

The above print should produce: `[1,2,3]`. This strategy also does an explicit array copy in the back ground but it is neat, more or less.

You could apply exactly the same strategy for your String array, by defining a TypeLiteral like:

```
   public static final TypeLiteral<List<String>> STRING_LIST =
            new TypeLiteral<List<STRING>>() {};
```

And obtaining the String list/array in Java scope via `...execute().as(STRING_LIST);`. This should give you your String array in the Java scope.